# Is autoscaling possible in vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, virtual-machine, haproxy, autoscaling

I am a newbie to vagrant. So far i know how to create multiple machines and provision them using a single vagrantfile. Currently i am working on a project which requires auto-scaling feature for an application. I am creating 3 VMs and provisioning them using chef. I would like to know is there way to create 4th vagrant VM and provision it at runtime when load increases on all 3 VMs (i.e. auto-scaling). I am using HAproxy as load balancer as my first VM.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

there's no reason what you could not provision your 4th VM automatically but there's no *auto scaling* feature built in with Vagrant.

Basically you will need to build a script to check the load on the VM or the load on your application, depending on which threshold you want to trigger a new VM.

There's no built-in capacity as:

- monitoring the load of the VM will be OS specific. do you want to turn a new VM when CPU/RAM reach a peak, you will need to check
- monitoring the load on your application would require you to monitor again depending your stack/framework of your app

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant is a tool for development and testing. It is *not* a production provisioning solution. Look at tools like Terraform, SparkleFormation, and CloudFormation.